# search algorithm within an ontology

Tags: algorithm, class, ontology

I have created a domain ontology using Protégé. This software allowed me to build an ontology in the OWL language. I am looking for an algorithm that will allow me to search and browse the created ontology. If I search for a concept, I will like the algorithm to give back the concept along with all its descendants.

For example, consider the partial ontology:

[image]

If I search for `Animal`, the algorithm will propose the following answer

```
   Animal Carnivore Lion
   OR
   Animal Herbivore Girafe
```

If you can help me, do not hesitate. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in at least 3 ways, depending on your needs:

(1) What you are talking about is called a classification algorithm and is realized by ontology reasoners. Reasoner(s) are already available in Protege and will update the concept hierarchy (if a reasoner is running) with inferred concepts.

(2) You can use the DL Query tab in Protege.

(3) If you want to programmatically classify the ontology, you can look at the [OWL API](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi), which will delegate reasoning to a configured reasoner.

Comment: OK I will try this thank you very much @Henriette Harmse